# How can I get the coordinates of an element inside SVG according to the document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

In jQuery you can do

```
$('div').offset()
```

and it returns the position of an element according to the document.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work with SVG elements.

Is there any way to get the absolute position of an SVG element just like it works for normal DOM elements?

Comment: Not sure in jquery, but if all else fails, you could try something like a jquery plugin for svg like http://keith-wood.name/svg.html which could help access svg elements, or one of the other libs like Raphael/Snap etc (may be overkill for what you need).

Answer (score 0):

This can be determened by using **clientX, clientY plus pageXOffset, pageYOffset.**

Try in html page:

```
<div id="svgDiv" style='width:400px;height:400px;'>
    <svg id="mySVG" width="400" height="400">
        <rect id="myRect" onmouseover="showMyComment(evt)"  onmouseout="hideMyComment()" x="100" y="100" width="100" height="100" fill="blue" />
    </svg>
</div>
<div style='position:absolute;visibility:hidden' id="myCommentDiv">This is my location</div>
```

with the code:

```
function showMyComment(evt)
{
    x=evt.clientX + window.pageXOffset
    y=evt.clientY + window.pageYOffset
    myCommentDiv.style.left=x+"px"
    myCommentDiv.style.top=y+"px"
    myCommentDiv.style.visibility="visible"
}
function hideMyComment()
{
  myCommentDiv.style.visibility="hidden"
}
```